# What is the difference between two ways of defining object methods in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, object

While reading this article https://medium.com/javascript-scene/the-single-biggest-mistake-programmers-make-every-day-62366b432308 by Eric Elliot, I came across the following type of object method definition.

```js
var obj = {
  getX() {
    document.write('X');
  }
}

obj.getX(); // X
```

How is it different than the following type of definition?

```js
var obj = {
  getX: function getX() {
    document.write('X');
  }
}

obj.getX(); // X
```

Comment: The first one isn't valid JS?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol why? It compiles and runs fine in my browser.

Comment: I tried running it to be sure. I get "expected ':'" as I thought I would... Whatever this is, it is not JavaScript.

Comment: The first one **IS** valid JS ...  what browser are you using @NiettheDarkAbsol ?

Comment: Huh, so it is. I have never seen that before though, must be something new XD Well, that's my "answer": the first one doesn't work in some (most?) browsers.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol First one doesn't work in internet explorer or safari ... works in firefox/chrome/edge/opera - that's all I can test ... your answer is relevant, because safari, IE10 and IE11 are still relevant

Comment: The 1st is a syntax sugar for the 2nd introduced in [ES6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/) (published in June of this year). The biggest difference currently is support, which the 1st is [partially limited by](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/), at the moment.

Comment: FYI, both work in current versions of Chrome, Firefox and Edge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first notation is ES2015/ES6 shorthand notation and will not work in safari or internet explorer

docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions

as the first is a shorthand notation for the second, that implies that there *is no difference* as far as functionality goes - however, until internet explorer is dead and buried and safari catches up (or follows internet explorer to the same grave) the first notation is not recommended for public facing sites as there is no possibility of "shim" or "polyfill" for syntax changes

most importantly, most "native mobile" browsers do not supports this (not talking about chrome/firefox for android etc)

Comment: Note: [Safari 9 and Edge do both support this syntax.](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-object_literal_extensions)

Comment: yes, I never said edge doesn't (safari 9 I'm not familiar enough with - just going by the MDN page)

Comment: Most people are compiling ES6 syntax changes to ES5 using something like Babel.